# What needs to be in my bootstrap script to join nodes to my EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm using a launch template for my node group and I'm getting an error saying `NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster` It seems that my issue is I need a bootstrap script to join the nodes to the cluster. This is my user data script, which is an example I found from this doc

**linux_user_data.tpl**
Script attempt #1

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
${pre_bootstrap_user_data ~}
export SERVICE_IPV4_CIDR=${cluster_service_ipv4_cidr}
B64_CLUSTER_CA=${cluster_auth_base64}
API_SERVER_URL=${cluster_endpoint}
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${cluster_name} ${bootstrap_extra_args} --b64-cluster-ca $B64_CLUSTER_CA --apiserver-endpoint $API_SERVER_URL
${post_bootstrap_user_data ~}
```

Script attempt #2

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh mtc-cluster
```

Script attempt #3

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh --apiserver-endpoint ${aws_eks_cluster.eks.endpoint} --b64-cluster-ca ${aws_eks_cluster.eks.certificate_authority}
```

Here's my launch template in Terraform that's supposed to use this user data script

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "node" {
  image_id                             = var.image_id
  instance_type                        = var.instance_type
  key_name                             = var.key_name
  name                                 = var.name
  user_data                            = base64encode("linux_user_data.tpl")

    block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 20
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my node group resource block as well

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "nodes_eks" {

  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks.name
  node_group_name = "eks-node-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.arn
  subnet_ids      = module.vpc.private_subnets

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 6
    min_size     = 3
  }

  ami_type             = "CUSTOM"
  capacity_type        = "ON_DEMAND"

  force_update_version = false

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.node.id
    version = aws_launch_template.node.default_version
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_worker_node_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_eks_cni_policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.amazon_ec2_container_registry_read_only,
  ]
}
```

Comment: And what does your user data script look like?

Comment: @MarkoE it’s the linux_user_data.tpl script up top, I tried it without paying attention and realized it has a lot of extra code in there (I’m assuming it relies on the EKS module I got it from). Do I just need the code that’s not an ‘if’ or ‘end if’ statement? 

Also as far as the script I want to run (I need to install Apache) I wanted to try to get everything up and running before I added the lines of code I need to the script

Comment: Not sure I follow. Prior to edit, there was another script from the terraform-aws-eks module and now you are using another one. Which is the one you are using?

Comment: @MarkoE Apologies it was late and I wasn't documenting everything, I just updated the post with all 3 scripts that I tried and all failed

Comment: And they all had the same error? Have you tried destroying and re-applying after each change? The thing with user data is that it runs only once, on instance creation. Do you have SSH access to any of the nodes? If so, you could find the logs and look for any obvious errors there. This is the location: /var/log/user-data.log.

Comment: @MarkoE Yeah I re-applied all of them and got the same error, the Nodes have SSH access, but they're failing to create. When I check my aws console the instances only pass 1/2 health checks and fail

Comment: @MarkoE The instances deploy fine before I introduced the launch template, could the ebs volume from the launch template be causing issues or could it still be the user data?

Comment: First question I have, for the first script: have you worked with `templatefile` before and do you know hot it works?

Comment: @MarkoE I don’t really know anything about template files unfortunately, I’ve seen pre and post boot user data mentioned in docs before, but this is my first time working with template files

Comment: Ok, let me try to think about how to create what you want to have. The first one will not work because you are not using the `templatefile` function so the user data will not look as you might expect it to.

Comment: @MarkoE For the 3rd script I even tried hardcoding the values after my first apply (The cluster got created so I went to the aws console and grabbed those values) and retried deploying the node group, but it failed again. Does having the wrong user data cause the instances themselves to fail? When I check the ec2 instance console they only pass 1/2 status checks

Comment: @MarkoE I know this is my first time doing this, but is it supposed to be this difficult? All I need are EKS nodes with an auto-scaling group, behind an ALB and a script to install apache. It sucks because I accomplished pretty much all of that with just the node group resource block, except the apache script part since I can't pass in user data directly and it has to be with a launch template. Whatever the best way to accomplish this is, I'll do it

Comment: As 1/2 status checks are passing, you have to make sure to understand the underlying reason, EKS or not. Here is the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html. As for your question should it be hard, for me it is one of the hardest things to get right unless you really understand what you are doing.

Comment: Which AMI are you using for the launch template, Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: @MarkoE yeah I’m trying to use Amazon Linux 2 for my nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code posted in the question and the documentation, the second example should work. However, I think that the file extension is what might be tripping up the nodes joining the cluster. The scripts defined in the first and third attempt require using the `templatefile` function [1] as the values cannot be provided to the script otherwise, even with interpolation defined properly as in

```
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh --apiserver-endpoint ${aws_eks_cluster.eks.endpoint} --b64-cluster-ca ${aws_eks_cluster.eks.certificate_authority}
```

The documentation [2] says that there are a couple of possibilities when providing the configuration to the nodes. Since you are using Amazon Linux 2, you should follow the explanation in [3]. In this case, you can use the `templatefile` function with the following template (let's use the name you already have, `linux_user_data.tpl`):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

--==MYBOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

#!/bin/bash
set -ex
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${cluster_name} \
  --container-runtime containerd

--==MYBOUNDARY==--
```

Since K8s version `1.24` is abandoning Docker as container runtime, the `--container-runtime` is set to `containerd`. With regard to functionality, there are no differences but this way (if you are not deploying 1.24) it will ease the transition. In the `aws_launch_template` resource, you would then have to change the following:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "node" {
  image_id       = var.image_id
  instance_type  = var.instance_type
  key_name       = var.key_name
  name           = var.name
  user_data      = base64encode(templatefile("${path.root}/linux_user_data.tpl", {
                   cluster_name = aws_eks_cluster.eks.name
  }))

    block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 20
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation says the only required argument is the cluster name, so try with this and update accordingly if needed. Also note the `path.root` usage, which means the `templatefile` will look for a file in the same directory where the root of the module is. If you were to modularize the code, then you could switch to `path.module`. More information about `path` can be found in [4].

EDIT: In order for the bootstrap script to work as expected, an EKS optimized AMI has to be used. The AMI ID per region can be found in [5].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html#launch-template-user-data

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html#launch-template-custom-ami

[4] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info

[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-optimized-ami.html

Comment: I still got the same error and my instances say ``` Instance reachability check failed``` Should I just post my entire code at this point?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to understand why that check failed. It could be the bootstrap script does not work as expected. Can you tell me the region and AMI id you are using?

Comment: I'm in us-west-2 using this AMI id ami-098e42ae54c764c35

Comment: Ok, can you find the EKS optimized AMI ID here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-optimized-ami.html and use that in your launch template and check if that will resolve the issue?

Comment: That ended up solving the issue, thank you! Can I just add whatever user data I want on top of that in between the boundaries?

Comment: I think so, but you will have to try it first. :)

Comment: I tried a few different variations and none seemed to properly install what I wanted, I'll just make a new question about it in a bit to make it easier to show what I tried

Comment: Sure, I will edit the answer so it's understood that the EKS optimized AMI should be used.